# Remove last last slash and everything after that MySQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) FROM path)
FROM   my_table
```

is working fine. But how to remove everything after the '/' and the '/' itself, too?

So the string

> http://mydomain.com/cde/abc/index.html

will become

> http://mydomain.com/cde/abc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest should be to just append a `/` to the string you're already calculating so it gets trimmed too;

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT('/', SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1)) FROM path)
FROM   my_table;
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a418/1).

Comment: That's clever Joachim